# Load all images and scripts for full website at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there anyway to load all images and scripts, not from the current webpage, but from the entire website on first load so that it's all cached.

I know this may not be best practice, but will come in handy.

Comment: Include all links and scripts in head portion.

Comment: it doesn't make any sense to me... but if that is what you want to achieve, you can think in terms of lazy loading of images or use something like web workers (though I am still in doubt whether they will serve your purpose)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Preface

Firstly, **this is a bad idea**. It will make your page load slower than it needs to, wasting *your* server resources and bandwidth on content that a visitor to your site *might not even need* (i.e. they only load that one page). Still, if this is really what you want, lets do this:

### Scripts

We can load scripts dynamically using Javascript:

```
var scriptUrls = ["a.js","b.js","c.js"];
for (i=0;i<scriptUrls.length;i++) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = scriptUrls[i];
    document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```

- In `scriptUrls` we define the paths from the file to the scripts that we want to load;
- Then we loop through for every item in `scriptUrls`;
- We create a new DOM element using `document.createElement("script")` - this makes a new `<script>` element - and assign this to be the value of the variable `script`;
- We set the `src` (source) attribute to be the value of the current URL in `scriptUrls`;
- And then we add the script element to the `<head>` of the HTML document (`document.head`) using the `.appendChild` method.

This is all we need to load scripts.

### Images

Images can be loaded in a similar fashion using Javascript, with a few differences:

```
var imgs = [];
var imgUrls = ["a.png","b.jpg","c.gif"];
for (i=0;i<imgUrls.length;i++) {
    imgs.push(new Image());
    imgs[i].src = imgUrls[i]
}
```

- `imgs` is in empty array, where we can store the image objects while they load. You can still use them on the page afterwards using the normal method `<img src="...">`; this is just a temporary thing to allow them to load properly;
- `imgUrls` is just an array of the URLS of all the images that you want to load;
- Now, we loop through `imgUrls`;
- `new Image()` creates a new Image object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image). We add this to the end of the `imgs` array `imgs.push`;
- Now, we set the source `src` of the image (`imgs[i].src` to the current item in the `imgUrls` array (`imgUrls[i]`).

This is all we need to load images.

### Note

You would put this as the first script in your head section. Just like, put all of this code in a JS file (i.e. `load.js`) and include it (`<script src="load.js"></script>`).

Comment: Interesting. Will this actually request and cache each image?

Comment: Yeah, you can see it in the dev tools if you want - Chrome has a network panel that shows all of that and I'm sure other browsers have something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it's not pretty or efficient.

All you need to do is include every script, link, reference, image, css and whatnot on your first page. For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="script_for_page_1" />
  <script src="script_for_page_2" />
  <script src="script_for_page_3" />
</head>
<body>
  <img src="image_from_page_one" style="opacity: 0" />
  <img src="image_from_page_one" style="opacity: 0" />
  <img src="image_from_page_one" style="opacity: 0" />
  <img src="image_from_page_two" style="opacity: 0" />
  <img src="image_from_page_two" style="opacity: 0" />
  <img src="image_from_page_two" style="opacity: 0" />
  <img src="image_from_page_two" style="opacity: 0" />
  <img src="image_from_page_three" style="opacity: 0" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a terrible solution. You realise that with `opacity:0` they're still going to be selectable and take up space on the page, right? Even if you set their style to `display:none` instead (and use a class, not in-line styling) this is still sub-optimal...